# Clarification about global extrema

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, optimization

Is everything in my statements $\textbf{(1)}$ and $\textbf{(2)}$ correct?

> - A real valued function $f$ defined on a domain $X$ has a global maximum point  at $x^{\bigstar}$ if $f(x^{\bigstar}) \geq f(x)$ for all $x$ in $X.$

$\textbf{(1)}\;\;$So $f(x^{\bigstar}) = f(x)$ **only** when the absolute maximum occurs at the **critical point**, as in an upside-down parabola (i.e., graph of $x^2$), or at the **endpoints**, as in an S-shaped graph (i.e., graph of $x^3$ bounded by $[a,b]$)? This is only referring to a function bounded on a closed interval.

> - A strict global maximum point can be defined: $x^{\bigstar}$ is a strict global maximum point if, for all $x$ in $X$ with $x \neq x^{\bigstar},$ we have $f(x^{\bigstar}) > f(x).$

$\textbf{(2)}\;\;$ How can $x \neq x^{\bigstar}$? If we **always** have to have an **interval** $\;I\;$ from which we choose optimal values, and the critical point $x^{\bigstar}$ must be in $\;I,\;$ then $x^{\bigstar}$ must be equal to some $x$ in $I$. This is only referring to a function on an open interval, i.e., $x^3$ on $(a,b),$ correct?. Even in an open interval, how can $x \neq x^{\bigstar}$?

Thanks.

Comment: You seem to suffer some deep misunderstanding about variables. While it is true that $x^*$ equals *some* $x$ (namely, $x^*$), it doesn't equal *every* $x$. So some $x$ is different from $x^*$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distinction is whether or not $x^\bigstar$ is the *only* point where the maximum value occurs. When they write "for all $x$ in $I$ with $x \neq x^\bigstar$" that means "for all *other* points in the interval".

For instance, take $f(x) \equiv 1$ on $[0,1]$. Then *any* point is a global maximum point; e.g. if $x^\bigstar = 0.5$, then it is true that $f(0.5) \geq f(x)$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.

Less degenerately, take $f(x) = \cos(x)$ on $[-4\pi,4\pi]$. Then $x^\bigstar = 0$ is a global maximum, because $\cos(0) = 1 \geq \cos(x)$ for all $x$ in this interval, but it is **not** a strict global max because, for instance $\cos(2\pi) = 1$ as well.

For a *strict* global max, $f(x) = -x^2$ on $[-1,1]$ works. Then obviously $x^\bigstar = 0$ is the maximum, and it is true that $f(0) > f(x)$ for all other $x$ in the interval (i.e. for all $x \neq 0$).

Comment: OK, thanks +1. So everything in (1) is correct?

Comment: Yes, as long as by "critical point" you mean "point where $f'(x) = 0$ **or** $f$ is not differentiable **or** $f$ is not continuous". (for instance, you can't find the maximum of $f(x) = -|x|$ just by setting the derivative $=0$).

Comment: I disagree that everything in (1) is correct, even with your (quite proper) caveats: The problem is not so much that it is incorrect; it is incoherent: There is no connection between the opening of the sentence (So $f(x^\bigstar)=f(x)$ only when …) and what follows.

Comment: Ok, yeah, I can agree with that. Any suggestions for the shortest path between OP's statement and a correct one?

Comment: @BaronVT OK, thanks again, I understand your examples except for the first example, where $f(x)=1$ on $[0,1].$ Can you elaborate more on this example please? Since it would be a horizontal line on y=1 through [0,1], would any point then be a global max and a global min? $f(0.5) \geq f(x)$ for $x \leq 0.5,$ but what about $0.6$ to $1$? $f(0.5)<f(0.6).$

Comment: No, $f(0.5)$ and $f(0.6)$ are **equal** (they are both $1$). You are correct that every point is both a global max and a global min.